# Checkboxes and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes that I need to make mutually exclusive;
I am using this code and it works:

```
$("input[name=ckbprf]").click(function () {                       
    $(this).closest("table").find("input").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

I need that if one of the checkboxes is already checked, it remains checked when I click on it. It may be unchecked just only when I click on an other one.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want mutually exclusive checkboxes, why not use radio buttons? They have this behaviour built in; no JS required

Comment: If for any reason (???) you still want to use checkboxes, then in click handler use: `this.checked=true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the checkbox checked if it is already checked like following.

```
 $("input[name=ckbprf]").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            return;
        }
        $(this).closest("table").find("input").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
```